# domain.save(validate: true, flush: true) doesn't change the record's state in db but no exception is thrown

Tags: hibernate

I have a spring job that publishes ids. In markPublishedRecord method I create a new TranslateRecord (which is a domain class mapped to translate_record table) and I save it. Problem is in db it appears to still have the previous status (IN_PROGRES) instead of having ERROR or COMPLETE but no exception is thrown in the code and also it logs             log.info("Successfully saved DB changes for id " + id); Any explanation why this is happening?
This is the code:

```
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
        List<List<String>> partitionedIds = partitionIds(items, 20);
        List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            partitionedIds.forEach(batch ->
                    futures.add(submit(() -> publishRecords(batch)
                    )));
        } finally {
            futures.forEach(future -> {
                try {
                    future.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    log.warn("Interrupted exception while publishing trials", ex);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    log.warn("Exception thrown while publishing trials. Job will fail.", e.getCause());
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void publishRecords(List<String> ids) {
        ids.stream().forEach(this::publish);
    }

    private void publish(String id) {
        boolean saveWithError = false;
        String errorMsg = null;
        Record record = loadRecord(id);
        if (record == null) {
            return;
        }
        log.info("Record with id " + id + " will be published to OQA");
        moveTranslatedInfo(id);

        try {
            RecordStatus status = saveWithError ? RecordStatus.ERROR : RecordStatus.COMPLETED;
            markPublishedRecord(record.getId(), status, errorMsg);
            log.info("Successfully saved DB changes for id " + id);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error while saving translate log for record with id " + id + " to db", ex);
            saveWithError = true;
        } finally {
            if (saveWithError) {
                context.incrementFailed();
            } else {
                context.incrementSucceeded();
            }
        }
    }

    @Retryable
    //used only for publish
    void markPublishedRecord(String id, RecordStatus status, String errorMsg) {
        Record.withNewSession { s ->
            Record.withNewTransaction { tx ->
                log.info("Saving publish details for id $id")
                def record = Record.read(id)
                TranslateRecord translateLog = new TranslateRecord(message: errorMsg, status: status)
                record.addTranslate(translateLog)
                record.save(validate: true, flush: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

To mention that this is happening rarely (last time happened in april) even though the jobs runs almost every day. Most of the times the record is in good shape in db.